# How to handle generated at JAVA side JSF Form?

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm generating my JSF Form html element at java (adding inputs, labels, etc) at `parseHtml()` method. I need to handle it. When I'm putting to every input value #{foo.bean} it shows me this symbols into input. How to do it correctly?

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "parserBean")
@RequestScoped
public class DataFormParserBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{fieldService}")
    private FieldService fieldService;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{builderBean}")
    private BuilderManagedBean builderManagedBean;

    private List<Field> fieldList;

    private List<Object> listWithData;

    private Integer index = 0;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        fieldList = fieldService.getListOfFields();
        listWithData = new ArrayList<>(fieldList.size());

    }

    public FieldService getFieldService() {
        return fieldService;
    }

    public void setFieldService(FieldService fieldService) {
        this.fieldService = fieldService;
    }

    public BuilderManagedBean getBuilderManagedBean() {
        return builderManagedBean;
    }

    public void setBuilderManagedBean(BuilderManagedBean builderManagedBean) {
        this.builderManagedBean = builderManagedBean;
    }

    /**
     * Method provides parsing String description of fields(from database) to
     * UIComponents and display them on screen
     * 
     * @return HtmlForm object that contains
     */
    public HtmlForm parseToHtml() {
        HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
        fieldList.forEach(item -> {
            form.getChildren().add(createLabel(item));
            form.getChildren().add(builderManagedBean.getMapWithBuilder().get(item.getType()).build(item, index));
            index += 1;
        });
        form.getChildren().add(createSubmitButton());
        return form;
    }

    private HtmlOutputLabel createLabel(Field field) {
        HtmlOutputLabel label = new HtmlOutputLabel();
        label.setValue(field.getLabel());
        return label;
    }

    private HtmlCommandButton createSubmitButton() {
        HtmlCommandButton button = new HtmlCommandButton();
        button.setValue("Add");
        button.setId("addDataButton");
        return button;
    }

}
```

And here I'm invoking this method and it shows me my form. But how I can handle it?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Add data</title>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <b:commandButton look="link" action="response?faces-redirect=true"
            value="#{responseBean.count}" />
        <b:commandButton look="link" action="fields?faces-redirect=true"
            value="Fields" />
    </h:form>


    <h:form binding="#{parserBean.parseToHtml()}">

    </h:form>
    <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/counter" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleMessage(data) {
            $('.display').html(data);
        }
    </script>
</h:body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE**
My web.xml file with configs

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JSF Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JSF Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JSF Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>fields.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: `it shows me this symbols into input` seems like JSF is not properly generating the page, do you have the servlet properly configured?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I don't know exactly, I'm newest at jsf. I'll add it to my post

Comment: @XtremeBiker check update pls

Comment: Do you have any strong reason to be doing the HTML stuff at managed bean? If it's a new project I strongly suggest you to avoid that practice and focus in view business in the managed bean.

Comment: @XtremeBiker i need only to add data from this form to database. and thats all. I can't understand, how to handle it

Comment: have a look to any good JSF 2 tuto. It looks as if you were mixing principles. Search for some updated tuto and implement it from the rush.

Comment: @XtremeBiker thanx for an answer, dude. but no tutorials found.